# How do I store recent searches in database?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I store recent queries in a database?? I know how to find recent searches which is inserted/modified the database but if it isn't inserted/modified then how do I find recent queries???

Answer (score 1):

You will want to enable MySQL's [General Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html). Taken directly from the site:

The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients.

Comment: I think you are referring to the log file which is created by mysql. but what I want is say I do have a site which is a search site. I want to show on my website what recent queries people made with a "Recent search" heading....

Comment: You'll need to store/cache all incoming queries to some form of persistent storage that you can query later. Whether that's your current database, file, etc. What's wrong with simply creating a table of recent searches where stashing them in there?

Comment: ok let me try I will revert back If I struck in the middle...Thanks